# Как в excel VBA добавить свой пункт в контекстное меню

Tags: excel, vba

Хотел добавить пункт в меню по вызову через правую кнопку мышки, который бы вставлял сегодняшнюю дату, в ячейку.
Вот такой код

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim MyButton As CommandBarButton
    Set MyButton = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=312)
    If MyButton Is Nothing Then
        Set MyButton = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        MyButton.Caption = "Insert Date"
        MyButton.OnAction = "InsertDate"
        MyButton.BeginGroup = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub InsertDate()
    ActiveCell.Value = Date
End Sub
```

Проблема заключается в том что он работает не правильно, дату он не вставляет, и постоянно при нажатие правой кнопки мышки создает еще новый пункт.
Как мне правильно добавить такой макрос.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код нужно поместить в модуль "ЭтаКнига". Он будет срабатывать при каждом открытии книги и добавлять нужный пункт контекстного меню.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
        .Caption = "Insert Date"
        .OnAction = "InsertDate"
        .FaceId = 125
        .BeginGroup = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Этот код нужно поместить в обычный модуль (создать, если его нет)

```
Sub InsertDate()
    ActiveCell.Value = Date
End Sub
```

[Доп. информация по вопросу здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg469862(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)